# Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer Exam Reading Material

Tags: magento2, certification

Recently `Magento` announces  **Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer Exam** exam for `Magento2` version.

After reading in this page https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-associate-developer-exam#.WqlJQ-bhVNA

I have some question about the exam.

What is the passing score for this exam?

which study materials can be useful for preparation for this exam?

and last, except `Free study Guide` any other study material available for this exam.

Are there any passing criteria for `EE edition` just like we have in `M1 Developer Plus Exam` ?

What is retake policy for this exam ?

How many free retake available?

Comment: This exam is based on Magento U course(include some exercise for better grasp concept).  Purpose only to check knowledge of Magento 2  completely. Not practical knowledge . so study guide would be Magento U content topics. this exam is yet to release (may be in may).

Answer (score 2):

This is what reply I got from magento team, I will let you know once they update this exam

[image]